# arrange array to become object array base on duplicate string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array and I want to arrange that to object array structure base on same string before dot, I want to create an object array structure to make it editable, so i can fill the value of each data on my array

```
var arr = ["data",
        "data.cell",
        "data.cell.celltiming",
        "data.cell.celltiming.0",
        "data.cell.celltiming.1",
        "data.cell.earfcn",
        "data.cell.pci",
        "data.cell.rsrp",
        "data.cell.rsrp.0",
        "data.cell.rsrp.1",
        "data.cell.rsrp.2",
        "data.cell.rsrq",
        "data.cell.rsrq.0",
        "data.cell.rsrq.1",
        "data.cell.rsrq.2",
        "data.cell.sinr",
        "data.cell.sinr.0",
        "data.cell.sinr.1",
        "data.cells",
        "data.cells.0",
        "data.cells.0.ch",
        "data.cells.0.ecno",
        "data.cells.0.r99",
        "data.cells.0.rscp",
        "data.cells.0.sc",
        "data.cells.1",
        "data.cells.1.ch",
        "data.cells.1.ecno",
        "data.cells.1.r99",
        "data.cells.1.rscp",
        "data.cells.1.sc",
        "data.cells.2",
        "data.cells.2.ch",
        "data.cells.2.ecno",
        "data.cells.2.r99",
        "data.cells.2.rscp",
        "data.cells.2.sc",
        "data.cells.3",
        "data.cells.3.ch",
        "data.cells.3.ecno",
        "data.cells.3.r99",
        "data.cells.3.rscp",
        "data.cells.3.sc",
        "data.id",
        "data.mac",
        "data.plmn",
        "data.rssi",
        "data.time",
        "deviceID",
        "time"]
```

how can i arrange that to become object array structure

```
var arr = [    "data": {
      "plmn": "",
      "id": "",
      "time": '',
      "cell": {
        "rsrp": [
          0,
          1,
          2
        ],
        "rsrq": [
          0,
          1,
          2
        ],
        "earfcn": '',
        "pci": '',
        "celltiming": [
          0,
          1
        ],
        "sinr": [
          0,
          1
        ]
      },
      "mac": ""
    },
    "time": '',
    "deviceID": ""]
```

I want to create an object array so i can fill the value of each key

Comment: what you tried for share code

Comment: @Bhargav i tried using map and slice but error... and confuse

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. Please show what you have tried. The objective is to help you fix **your code**

Comment: @charlietfl i know it, but i still not understand about array.map(function(d,i){ var t = d.split('.') if (t...try many thing) }) im stuck can you help me

Comment: What you are asking is fairly complex and not trivial

Comment: @charlietfl  that is way im asking without including the code, cos i still working on it, not giving result yet but i will share if i can make it... thanks for looking up my question

Comment: what are the rules? when does a substring become a key of an object and when does it become a value in an array? what happened to the "cells" substring and its dependents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the following:

1. [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b), accumulating over an empty object `{}`,
2. A reference (`ref`) to the `accumulator` object,
3. [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to extract individual `key`s (substrings) from the current string in the array,
4. Iterating over the `key`s to progress along the `key` "chain",

   a. If a `key` doesn't already exist in the `accumulator` object, create an object at that key, i.e. `if (!ref[key]) ref[key] = {}`

   b. Continue to traverse the `accumulator` object by re-setting the reference (`ref`), i.e. `ref = ref[key]`
5. Move to the next string in the original array

```js
var arr = ["data",
  "data.cell",
  "data.cell.celltiming",
  "data.cell.celltiming.0",
  "data.cell.celltiming.1",
  "data.cell.earfcn",
  "data.cell.pci",
  "data.cell.rsrp",
  "data.cell.rsrp.0",
  "data.cell.rsrp.1",
  "data.cell.rsrp.2",
  "data.cell.rsrq",
  "data.cell.rsrq.0",
  "data.cell.rsrq.1",
  "data.cell.rsrq.2",
  "data.cell.sinr",
  "data.cell.sinr.0",
  "data.cell.sinr.1",
  "data.cells",
  "data.cells.0",
  "data.cells.0.ch",
  "data.cells.0.ecno",
  "data.cells.0.r99",
  "data.cells.0.rscp",
  "data.cells.0.sc",
  "data.cells.1",
  "data.cells.1.ch",
  "data.cells.1.ecno",
  "data.cells.1.r99",
  "data.cells.1.rscp",
  "data.cells.1.sc",
  "data.cells.2",
  "data.cells.2.ch",
  "data.cells.2.ecno",
  "data.cells.2.r99",
  "data.cells.2.rscp",
  "data.cells.2.sc",
  "data.cells.3",
  "data.cells.3.ch",
  "data.cells.3.ecno",
  "data.cells.3.r99",
  "data.cells.3.rscp",
  "data.cells.3.sc",
  "data.id",
  "data.mac",
  "data.plmn",
  "data.rssi",
  "data.time",
  "deviceID",
  "time"
]
var obj = arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) => {
  let ref = accumulator;
  currentValue.split(".").forEach(key => {
    if (!ref[key]) ref[key] = {}
    ref = ref[key];
  })
  return accumulator;
}, {})

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, "\t"));
```

This gets you most of the way. Now all you need to do is:

1. Traverse the object (first pass), replacing empty objects with empty strings, then

   ```
   arr.forEach(chain => { // first pass, change empty objects to empty strings
     let ref = obj;
     chain.split(".").forEach(key => {
       if (Object.keys(ref[key]).length === 0) {
         ref[key] = ''
       } else {
         ref = ref[key]
       }
     })
   })
   ```
2. Traverse the object (second pass), checking when all of the keys of an object are numbers and all of the values are empty strings, and replacing this object with an array of the keys.

   ```
   function keysAreNumbersAndValuesAreEmptyStrings(object) {
     let entries = Object.entries(object);
     for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
       let key = entries[i][0], value = entries[i][1];
       if(isNaN(Number(key)) || typeof value !== "string" || value.length !== 0) return false;
     }
     return true;
   }

   arr.forEach(chain => { // second pass, change objects whose keys are numbers to an array of those keys
     let ref = obj;
     chain.split(".").forEach(key => {
       if (typeof ref[key] === "object" && keysAreNumbersAndValuesAreEmptyStrings(ref[key])) {
         ref[key] = Object.keys(ref[key]).map(val => Number(val));
       } else {
         ref = ref[key]
       }
     })
   })
   ```

Complete solution: https://jsfiddle.net/s2attatz/1/

```js
var arr = ["data",
  "data.cell",
  "data.cell.celltiming",
  "data.cell.celltiming.0",
  "data.cell.celltiming.1",
  "data.cell.earfcn",
  "data.cell.pci",
  "data.cell.rsrp",
  "data.cell.rsrp.0",
  "data.cell.rsrp.1",
  "data.cell.rsrp.2",
  "data.cell.rsrq",
  "data.cell.rsrq.0",
  "data.cell.rsrq.1",
  "data.cell.rsrq.2",
  "data.cell.sinr",
  "data.cell.sinr.0",
  "data.cell.sinr.1",
  "data.cells",
  "data.cells.0",
  "data.cells.0.ch",
  "data.cells.0.ecno",
  "data.cells.0.r99",
  "data.cells.0.rscp",
  "data.cells.0.sc",
  "data.cells.1",
  "data.cells.1.ch",
  "data.cells.1.ecno",
  "data.cells.1.r99",
  "data.cells.1.rscp",
  "data.cells.1.sc",
  "data.cells.2",
  "data.cells.2.ch",
  "data.cells.2.ecno",
  "data.cells.2.r99",
  "data.cells.2.rscp",
  "data.cells.2.sc",
  "data.cells.3",
  "data.cells.3.ch",
  "data.cells.3.ecno",
  "data.cells.3.r99",
  "data.cells.3.rscp",
  "data.cells.3.sc",
  "data.id",
  "data.mac",
  "data.plmn",
  "data.rssi",
  "data.time",
  "deviceID",
  "time"
]
var obj = arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) => {
  let ref = accumulator;
  currentValue.split(".").forEach(key => {
    if (!ref[key]) ref[key] = {}
    ref = ref[key];
  })
  return accumulator;
}, {})

    arr.forEach(chain => { // first pass, change empty objects to empty strings
      let ref = obj;
      chain.split(".").forEach(key => {
        if (Object.keys(ref[key]).length === 0) {
          ref[key] = ''
        } else {
          ref = ref[key]
        }
      })
    })

    function keysAreNumbersAndValuesAreEmptyStrings(object) {
      let entries = Object.entries(object);
      for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        let key = entries[i][0], value = entries[i][1];
        if(isNaN(Number(key)) || typeof value !== "string" || value.length !== 0) return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    arr.forEach(chain => { // second pass, change objects whose keys are numbers to an array of those keys
      let ref = obj;
      chain.split(".").forEach(key => {
        if (typeof ref[key] === "object" && keysAreNumbersAndValuesAreEmptyStrings(ref[key])) {
          ref[key] = Object.keys(ref[key]).map(val => Number(val));
        } else {
          ref = ref[key]
        }
      })
    })

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, "\t"));
```

```
/*
{
  "data": {
    "cell": {
      "celltiming": [
        0,
        1
      ],
      "earfcn": "",
      "pci": "",
      "rsrp": [
        0,
        1,
        2
      ],
      "rsrq": [
        0,
        1,
        2
      ],
      "sinr": [
        0,
        1
      ]
    },
    "cells": {
      "0": {
        "ch": "",
        "ecno": "",
        "r99": "",
        "rscp": "",
        "sc": ""
      },
      "1": {
        "ch": "",
        "ecno": "",
        "r99": "",
        "rscp": "",
        "sc": ""
      },
      "2": {
        "ch": "",
        "ecno": "",
        "r99": "",
        "rscp": "",
        "sc": ""
      },
      "3": {
        "ch": "",
        "ecno": "",
        "r99": "",
        "rscp": "",
        "sc": ""
      }
    },
    "id": "",
    "mac": "",
    "plmn": "",
    "rssi": "",
    "time": ""
  },
  "deviceID": "",
  "time": ""
}
*/
```